# Mailwizz Need to update pepipost API Code

Tags: mail-server

I have checked mailwizz delivery (pepipost API ) server code. Need to update the API code. Pepipost API changed the API Url and request parameters.

Comment: @twisted1919 You can check.

Comment: We'll look into this asap.